# Expression Engine Join Channels

Tags: expressionengine

I'm pretty new to Expression Engine and am struggling with the following.  I have a properties channel and a property_images channel.   A property can have one or more images.

I'd like to display list of properties including an image and summary information. Users should be able to click through to view property detail page showing all property details and all images.

PropertyID is common to both channels but I can't work out how to do the join.  Is this possible "out of the box" or do i need to use an add-on ... if the latter, any recommendations would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

How are you currently connecting your Property entries with your Property Images entries? Do you just have a Property ID field in each channel, and you're manually entering it in each location?

I'd suggest instead using [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa), which is a many-to-many relationship add-on. Add a "Property Images" field to your Properties channel, make it a Playa field, and select your Property Images channel as the source. You can then select as many entries from the Property Images channel as "related" to each property while editing that property entry, and display them using Playa's module tags on the front-end.

Alternately, you could use [Matrix](http://pixelandtonic.com/matrix) or [Assets](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets), both also by Pixel and Tonic, to add your property images directly to your property listings (that will save queries when displaying you data on the front-end).